# TStream not converted to TStrings

Tags: delphi, indy10

I've checked the size of the stream and it's the same size on both the server and the client, so I think there isn't any data loss there. Should I use a different procedure to load the string from the stream?

Client code:

```
StreamSize:= TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadInt64;  //<Size of TStream

TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadStream(TStream(NotificationStream), StreamSize);

NotificationStrings := ConvertStreamToStrings(NotificationStream);
Notifications := ConvertStringsToNotifications(NotificationStrings);

Synchronize(procedure begin PutNotifications(Notifications); end);
StreamSize:= 0;
```

Convert stream function:

```
function ConvertStreamToStrings(ntfStream : TStream) : TStringList;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  Result.LoadFromStream(ntfStream, TEncoding.Default);
end;
```

Comment: Yes. Your current `ConvertStreamToStrings` function will lead to an access violation.

Comment: Why does it lead to an access violation?

Comment: Because of the reason given ↓

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create the `TStringList` object that `ConvertStreamToStrings()` returns. Add this:

```
Result := TStringList.Create;
```

before the call to `LoadFromStream()`.

Of course, you also need to `Free()` the **returned** `TStringList` when you don't need it anymore.

**Edit after comments**

Also, you need to reset the stream's `Position` to 0 before you can load it to the `TStringList`, so the conversion function would look like this:

```
function ConvertStreamToStrings(ntfStream: TStream): TStringList;
begin
  ntfStream.Position := 0;
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  Result.LoadFromStream(ntfStream, TEncoding.Default);
end;
```

Comment: I've added the create, but the list is still empty.

Comment: What is the size of NotificationStream after ReadStream?

Comment: Set ntfStream.Position := 0; before LoadFromStream

Comment: Personally, I would reset the `Position` after `ReadStream()` exits and before calling `ConvertStreamToStrings()`.  That would make `ConvertStreamToStrings()` more reusable, in case you ever want to pass a `TStream` to it where the string data does not start at position 0.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Tom said, if you are willing/able to change your protocol then Indy's `TIdIOHandler` class has methods for sending/reading `TStrings` data directly so you don't have to use a `TStream`, eg.

```
...IOHandler.Write(NotificationStrings, True);
```

```
NotificationStrings := TStringList.Create;
...IOHandler.ReadStrings(NotificationStrings);
```